# Change "accuracy" attribute for Emulator location in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using emulator's location simulator service. I am able to set location and even emulate routes. But couldn't find a way to change "accuracy" attribute of the location. How can I do that?
[image]